# MonoDevelop makefile generation cannot find NUnit

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, autotools

I have a solution in MonoDevelop (version 5.7 on Ubuntu 14.04) made up of 2 projects. One of those projects depends on NUnit. I enabled makefile integration and running `./autogen.sh` works fine. However when I run `make` I get the following error:

`make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../../../../../nunit.framework', needed by 'bin/Release/test.dll'.  Stop.`

Additionally, even though I have enabled separate build target names for each of my two projects, it refuses to accept those targets in `make <target>`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to fix it by deleting all the generated files and restarting the process selecting "Project" as the master as opposed to the "Makefile" option. Now it compiles fine.